# Bash or condition in IF

Tags: bash, if-statement

Why does the OR condition not work in the following bash script?

```
read number
if [ "$number" != 1 -o "$number" != 2 ] ; then  echo not 1 or 2   fi
if [ "$number" == 1 -o "$number" == 2] ; then   echo 1 or 2  fi 
exit
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first one be `[ "$number" != 1 -a "$number" != 2 ]` ?

Comment: You should always specify *in what way* it doesn't work. What result are you expecting, what result are you actually getting, and for which input does this happen?

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for wasting your time, I should've used -a instead of -o. I was getting the output "not 1 or 2" no matter what value number had.

Comment: You shouldn't use either `-o` or `-a`; use `[ ... ] || [ ... ]` for OR, `[ ... ] && [ ... ]` for AND. If you don't need POSIX compatibility, use `[[ ... || ... ]]` and `[[ ... && ... ]]` instead of `[ ... ]`. You also should not use `==` with `[`; POSIX doesn't support the `==` operator (use `=`), and if it *does* work, it most likely means that you can use `[[` which supports `==`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it works:

```
#!/bin/bash
read number
if [ "$number" != 1 -o "$number" != 2 ];then
    echo not 1 or 2
fi
if [ "$number" == 1 -o "$number" == 2 ];then
    echo 1 or 2
fi
exit
```

output:

```
[~]$./test1.sh 
2
not 1 or 2
1 or 2
```

anyway according to the right syntax and your first output message you should use this:

```
#!/bin/bash
read number
if [ "$number" -ne 1 ] && [ "$number" -ne 2 ];then
     echo not 1 or 2
fi
if [ "$number" -eq 1 ] || [ "$number" -eq 2 ];then
    echo 1 or 2
fi
exit
```

output:

```
[~]$./test1.sh 
1
1 or 2
[~]$./test1.sh 
2
1 or 2
[~]$./test1.sh 
3
not 1 or 2
[~]$./test1.sh 
4
not 1 or 2
```

Best Regards
Claudio